# integrate $\int \frac{dx}{1+cos^2x}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}$$

I used $\cos x=\frac{1-v^2}{1+v^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2dv}{1+v^2}$

and got $$2\int \frac{dv}{v^4-v^2+1}=2\int \frac{dv}{(v^2-\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}arctan(\frac{2v^2-1}{\sqrt{3}})+c$$

How to continue?

Comment: You can use partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Depending on OP's purpose, it might be better to apply partial fractions over $\Bbb R$, in which case one wants to use the real factorization into the irreducible *quadratic* factors of the denominator. One can save some time when working out the factorization using the fact that the denominator is even to conclude that it must have the form $(v^2 + a v + 1)(v^2 - a v + 1)$.

Comment: Complete the square: $v^4-v^2+1=v^4-v^2+1/4+3/4=(v^2-1/2)^2+3/4$.

Comment: You can't jump straight to arctan because you would need to substitute $u=v^2-1/2$, but you do not have the factor of $v$ required to make this substitution perform correctly.

Comment: @Ian just what I thought now

Comment: @Ian I did not understand why can not I jump to arctan?

Comment: @gbox The arctan integral is of the form $\frac{du}{u^2+a^2}$. To get to this form you would need to substitute $u=v^2-1/2$, but this would give $du=2vdv$, and you don't have the factor of $v$ in the original integrand to get "absorbed" into the du. If you could avoid that then you could do all sorts of crazy things like "prove" $\int \frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \ln(x^2+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative method:

Multiplying through by $sec^2(x)$:

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x} = \int \frac{sec^2x}{1+sec^2x}dx$$

Defining $u = tanx$, $du = sec^2x$ $dx$, and using the identity $1+tan^2x = sec^2x$:

$$\int \frac{sec^2x}{1+sec^2x}dx = \int \frac{1}{u^2+2}du$$

The integral is now of the form of a very well-known $\arctan$ integral

Comment: Your actual centered formula is correct but you wrote the identity you were using backwards. (You meant $\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$. I remember this one by either rederiving it as necessary, or by looking at the values at zero.)

Comment: @Ian Thank you for catching my mistake! :)

Comment: so I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}arctan(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}})+C=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}arctan(\frac{tanx}{\sqrt{2}})+C$?

Comment: @gbox That's right. You can check it on Wolfram.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$.  Then,

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\cos^2(x)}\,dx=\int \frac{2}{3+\cos(2x)}\,dx$$

Enforcing the substitution $x=u/2$ yields

$$ \int \frac{2}{3+\cos(2x)}\,dx=\int \frac{1}{3+\cos(u)}\,du \tag 1$$

Now, making the [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) in $(1)$, as in the OP, we find

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\cos^2(x)}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(u/2)}{\sqrt 2}\right)+C=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt 2}\right)+C$$

Comment: I did not get it, the first attempt gives a different answer?

Comment: Keep trying.  You'll get it.